# Changing and moving backgrounds HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for the place that I work at (an ice cream shop).  I mentioned that It'd be fun to make the website, but now I feel way out of my depth.  I was just going to do something real simple and easy to use, but my boss has requested some more complicated stuff.  Something that I'm really having trouble with is shifting of the background like here:   \

1. https://www.wix.com/
2. http://monikoskitchen.com/

I'd really like to learn how to do this, and I can't back out now either (already been paid).  How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called Parallax effect. I am guessing but I think that's what you want. You can find a lot of plugins for achieving this.

- http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js
- https://tgomilar.github.io/paroller.js

to name a few

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as useful if it helps you! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)